# the centos in docker how to chkconfig service?

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, docker, centos

I have install docker in my mac, then pull and run centos at the docker.

I config the service:

```
chkconfig nginx on
chkconfig php-fpm on
chkconfig mysql on
```

But when I restart the docker container, the service won't start at the boot, how to config?

Comment: See if this documentation link helps -https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/host_integration/#systemd

Comment: @Rao, I mean restart container, not attach the runing container.